# Technology used to built apex and VisualForce in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am a newbie to Salesforce. I was just wondering on what technologies is VisualForce and apex built. I  I wish to know the exact technology on which these sales force technology components are built, as I am curious and I did not get any concrete answer yet on internet. Some of my technical counterparts told it's built on electron.js, but I did not find anything to justify this on internet. This made me all the more curious. Please help me out to know on what technology is s VisualForce and apex built?

Comment: apex is based on Java.

Comment: Hi Vijaya, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. As stated, this question is way too broad to be on topic, and it also shows no research. A good question will demonstrate that you've already tried to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This Salesforce blog [Apex Runtime Update for Developer Edition Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/12/apex-runtime-update-for-de-orgs.html) announced that Apex was changing to be compiled directly to Java byte code rather than being interpreted. Hence Apex runs in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Visualforce appears to be built on top of [JavaServer Faces](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) but I have never seen any Salesforce documentation that says that.

The platform consists of those and many other pieces of technology brought together to provide a Platforms As A Service ([PAAS](https://www.salesforce.com/ap/paas/overview/)) offering. Read this [The Force.com Multitenant Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture) documentation for a broad overview.

Comment: I suspected similar musings. You can disguise a technology only so much...